# using 'or' with lookbehind assertions python regexes

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to create a mandatory lookbehind/ahead amongst a few options, to split names of a namespace. I have:

```
(?<=^)|(?<=[=*%&^|<>,.(){}[\]'"\s])\w+(?=[=*%&^|<>,.(){}[\]'"\s])|(?=$)
```

The way I read it is "if there's a word with the beginning of a line or one of these splitter characters behind it, AND an end of line or splitter character after it, it's a name for the namespace"

But when ran with:

```
dict['key']
```

It grabs the key part, not the dict. This is baffling, because it accepts the or part of after the word, but not before. What should be changed to grab dict first, then key? Thank you

Comment: Your ORs split the *entire* regex into separate parts. Add parentheses around the two first lookbehinds.

Comment: Your lookahead and lookbehind aren't matching with any text. Perhaps you mean to group something like `(^|(?<=[...]))\w+($|(?=[...]))`. Like that, it would get words starting a line or preceded by one of your characters, and ending the line or followed by a character. That, or use non-matching groups like `(?:^|[...])`.

Comment: If you are trying to consume Python syntax, I would suggest using [`ast.parse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse) instead.

Comment: @Ken: You might as well post that as an answer, but they're called **non-capturing** groups, and you would need to use a **capturing** group to extract the part you're interested in.